# How to return range of cells above a value in a specified column into a new worksheet

Tags: vba, select, excel

This is a very basic question but I was unable to find an answer to it using the search function.

I have a `worksheet` that contains the value `Total Settled Deposits` and `Successful Deposits` both in `column B`, but the row numbers the values are in changes depending on information that is submitted in between the values.

I would like to write `VBA` code that would do this: return the range in between and including the Total `Settled Deposits` cell and `Successful Deposits` cell into a new `worksheet`.

For example, if `Total Settled Deposits` is located in cell `B:12` and `Successful Deposits` is in `B:7`, return the values in range `B7:P13`. I would like the values returned in a new worksheet titled `abc`.

Comment: I think you should give a more full example of a before and after of the data as well as what you have attempted to solve the issue

Comment: You say 'I would like to write VBA code', but it sounds like you are asking someone else to do it for you. Try it yourself and if you get stuck, ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA just do this. Add new sheet named abc, in B1 add this formula:

```
=IF(AND(ROW()>=MATCH("Successful Deposits",Sheet1!B:B,0),ROW()<=MATCH("Total Settled Deposits",Sheet1!B:B,0)),Sheet1!B1,"")
```

And drag it down. it will leave all of column B blank except for the matching cells on the other sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub Zero()
    Set r1 = Range("B:B").Find(what:="Successful Deposits")
    Set r2 = Range("B:B").Find(what:="Total Settled Deposits")
    Set r3 = Range(r1, r2)
    addy = r3.Address
    Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "abc"
    r3.Copy Range(addy)
End Sub
```